# Visual Basic Excel - Trying to copy cells based on a counter

Tags: vba, excel, range, cells

So I have a column A where the cells from 143 to 179 can be filled in with data if required. The loop takes the data from A and removes cells that have not been filled in getting rid of all the spaces (apart from a few listed required for formatting) and puts them into column C.

So, problem is that the script copies from 143 to 179 even if only 4 of the cells were filled in which looks strange when copied onto our system as there is a massive space. Is there a way to have it so it just copies/selects what's filled in, ex C143:"C"&counter ?

```
For i = 143 To 179
    If i = 163 Or i = 165 Or i = 174 Then counter = counter + 1 
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Cells(counter + 143, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
Next i    

Range("C143:C179").Select 
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: `Range("C143:C" & counter).Copy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but if you just want to copy the cells that have values in column A, to column c, starting from cell C1, this could do the job. I am not sure why you wanted to skip some of the rows, but I commented that out, however if you really need that you can bring it back to the code.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = ActiveSheet
    counter = 1

    For i = 143 To 179
        'If i = 163 Or i = 165 Or i = 174 Then counter = counter + 1
            If WS.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
                WS.Cells(counter, 3).Value = WS.Cells(i, 1).Value
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
    Next i

    WS.Range("C1:C" & counter - 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks. Its for admin checks, like to keep spacing between different types of checks, purely aesthetic. All very interesting I know.

Comment: @J.Macc since you are new to the forum, when you get your answer there is a check mark next to the answers that if you click it will turn green meaning that you received what you wanted and it will actually give credits to the person who wrote the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set the value up as a variable.  Something like this:

```
For i = 143 To 179
    If i = 163 Or i = 165 Or i = 174 Then counter = counter + 1 
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Cells(counter + 143, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
Next i    

lastrow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("C143:C" & lastrow1).Select 
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: I am very embarrassed I didn't think of this thank you kindly.

Comment: No problem! If this answer worked for you i'd greatly appreciate if you could accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left :)